# async javascript - how is this code going to run?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, spreadsheet

I have an app survey like that saves some data to 3 google spreadsheets. When the user finishes answering questions and clicks the send button, the following code is going to be invoked:

```
doc.addRow(first_sheet_name, first_object, err => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    doc.addRow(second_sheet_name, second_object, err => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        doc.addRow(third_sheet_name, third_object, err => {
            if (err) console.log(err)
        })
    })
});
```

Now, what is going to happen when some users gonna click at the exact same moment? In my spreadsheet, I want the e.g. 5th row to have data(answers for survey) from the same person.

Comment: That's a terrible way to write code. You have to be DRY. And I'm not very familiar with Google docs API but if were talking just JavaScript then the click won't happen until that code finishes executing.

Comment: If two users click at the same time, the responses from the server can be received in any order b/c of network latency, etc. So you should build something that can tolerate that. Don't know the spreadsheet api either, but maybe you could get the row # from the first request, and then update the same row in the other 2 spreadsheets...